# matching only bold tag with regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the `<b>` tag or `<b style=".....">`
by using a regular expression like

```
<(/)?(b)[^>]*>
```

it not only matches the `b` tag but all the tags starting with `b`

Comment: [Obligatory link whenever someone wants to use regular expressions for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: Just to partially justify such a question is one use of a regex just MIGHT be usage in a editor like Visual Studio where you want to find/edit a mass of stuff in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a word boundary (`\b`):

```
<(/)?(b\b)[^>]*>
```

This ensures that the next character after the `<b` must not be a 'word' character (a letter, number or underscore).

Of course, this could match a tag like `<b-foo>`, which might be a concern. In that case, I'd recommend using a lookahead like this:

```
<(/)?(b(?=[\s>]))[^>]*>
```

This ensures that the next character after the `<b` must either be a whitespace character, or a `>`.

Comment: Or just make the RegEx match a proper "<b>" tag: `<(/)?(b)>`. Inline styling on a "<b>" tag is simply bad practice.

Comment: `<(/)?(b)(?:\s+[^>]*)?>`

Comment: @tenub yup, that would be a valid solution. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this:

```
/<\/?b.*?>/g
```

Your regex:

```
/<(\/)?(b)[^>]*>/g
```

You may want to use the global modifier as per the syntax of your language of use. The one I've used is Javascript.

Comment: "but I think both my and your regex needs global modifier. g" OK so add that, with the assumption they do NOT know how.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, to find and replace all `<b> and </b>` tags, you'd do something like this:

```
const myStr = '<b>Hello</b>';
myStr.replace(/<[/]?(b)>/gi, '');
console.log(myStr); // Outputs 'Hello' with the bold tags removed
```

Hope that helps someone.